# The use of else: would give an invalid syntax

Tags: python-3.x

The problem is that else: is showing up as error on line-28

```
from IPython.display import clear_output
print("Welcome to Tic Tac Toe")
while True:

    theBoard = [' '] * 10   
    player_input()
    choose_first(1,2)
    play_game = input('Ready to play? y or n')
if play_game == 'y':
        game_on = True
else:
    game_on= False

while game_on:
    if choose_first==1:
        place_marker(test_board,player1_marker)
        display_board(test_board)

    if win_check(the_board, playa1_marker):
        display_board(the_board)
        print('Player 1 has won!!')
        game_on =(False)

    else:
        if full_board_check(theBoard):
            display_board(theBoard)
            print('The game is a draw!')
            break
            else:
                turn = ('Player 2')

else:
    display_board(theBoard)
    position = player_choice(theBoard)
    place_marker(theBoard, player_2marker, position)

if win_check(theBoard, player2_marker):
    display_board(theBoard)
    print('Player 2 has won!')
    game_on = False
    else:
        if full_board_check(theBoard):
        display_board(theBoard)
        print('The game is a draw!')
        break
else:
turn = 'Player 1'
if not replay():
        break
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you please tell us which line is line 28? It would take a lot of time for us to count. Also, please include only the code that we need to see in order to answer your question. This helps us a lot. Thanks!

Comment: What's the exact error with trace? Also, is all of the indentation here exactly as it is in your actualy code?

Comment: Also, could you tell us what you are trying to achieve? It's unclear what this is code is supposed to do.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this part of the code:

```py
else:
        if full_board_check(theBoard):
            display_board(theBoard)
            print('The game is a draw!')
            break#here is the problem
            else:
                turn = ('Player 2')
```

After the `break` statement, you can't have anything else in the loop. This is a simple error.

To fix this, put the else before the break. Like so:

```py
else:
        if full_board_check(theBoard):
            display_board(theBoard)
            print('The game is a draw!')
            break#here is the problem
        else:
            turn = ('Player 2')
```

So, this would be your entire code:

```py
from IPython.display import clear_output
print("Welcome to Tic Tac Toe")
while True:

    theBoard = [' '] * 10   
    player_input()
    choose_first(1,2)
    play_game = input('Ready to play? y or n')
if play_game == 'y':
        game_on = True
else:
    game_on= False

while game_on:
    if choose_first==1:
        place_marker(test_board,player1_marker)
        display_board(test_board)

    if win_check(the_board, playa1_marker):
        display_board(the_board)
        print('Player 1 has won!!')
        game_on =(False)

    else:
        if full_board_check(theBoard):
            display_board(theBoard)
            print('The game is a draw!')
            break
        else:
            turn = ('Player 2')

else:
    display_board(theBoard)
    position = player_choice(theBoard)
    place_marker(theBoard, player_2marker, position)

if win_check(theBoard, player2_marker):
    display_board(theBoard)
    print('Player 2 has won!')
    game_on = False
    else:
        if full_board_check(theBoard):
        display_board(theBoard)
        print('The game is a draw!')
        break
else:
turn = 'Player 1'
if not replay():
        break
```

I think this is what you meant. It was a simple indentation error.

Hopefully, this helps!

Answer (score 0):

you have one tab to many there. the else needs to be exactly under the if statement. this should work:

```
from IPython.display import clear_output
print("Welcome to Tic Tac Toe")
while True:
    theBoard = [' '] * 10
    player_input()
    choose_first(1,2)
    play_game = input('Ready to play? y or n')
if play_game == 'y':
    game_on = True
else:
    game_on= False

while game_on:
    if choose_first==1:
        place_marker(test_board,player1_marker)
        display_board(test_board)

    if win_check(the_board, playa1_marker):
        display_board(the_board)
        print('Player 1 has won!!')
        game_on =(False)

    else:
        if full_board_check(theBoard):
            display_board(theBoard)
            print('The game is a draw!')
            break
        else:
            turn = ('Player 2')

else:
display_board(theBoard)
position = player_choice(theBoard)
place_marker(theBoard, player_2marker, position)

if win_check(theBoard, player2_marker):
    display_board(theBoard)
    print('Player 2 has won!')
    game_on = False
else:
    if full_board_check(theBoard):
        display_board(theBoard)
    print('The game is a draw!')
    break
else:
turn = 'Player 1'
if not replay():
    break
```

Comment: It still isnt work for the else: on line 45 it is saying invalid syntax why is that?

Comment: the indents there got a bit confused in the copy paste. you need to fix that